# How to automatically tweet when a new article added to Joomla

Tags: php, twitter, joomla

I have a free wordpress blog which automatically tweets my new article through my twitter account which I have no idea how wordpress does it. I want to do the same thing on Joomla 3.2.3 platform.

What I want to do is when I add a new article into a specific category, I want Joomla to tweet the article's url automatically.

What I have tried is to search for a couple of components doing this. But I am stucked at API/Key-API/Secret validation. The component (AutoTweetNG) needs tweeter API to have read and write level. So I have many web sites to apply this application. In order to have read and write rights twitter asks me to enter mobile phone number in the profile page.

I have decided to make this by hard coding. Is there any oppurtunity to achieve this? It looks it is gonna be a little robot things, and twitter does not let me.

At least it would be great if thic could be done using PHP only.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what you are asking. There are a number of extensions that will automatically tweet for you. Yes, you need to use the Twitter API, you cannot just send a tweet via an account without giving permission and confirming that the application tweeting is a registered application that the user has shared. It wouldn't make sense to let you tweet to an account that belongs to someone you don't know or who hasn't given you permission.  Why is it that you don't want to use a normal twitter extension?

Comment: You **do** need the twitter API to achieve this. That's why the components you mentioned use it. Just do as they say, they have step by step instructions. If multi post is needed you'll have to do the same for the other websites.

Comment: @Elin Of course I have to use Twitter API but it asks me to enter mobile phone number in order to have read and write permission for the website which belongs to my organization.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

You can achieve it using two things in Joomla, One is create a twitter Oauth APP also create a content plugin for auto tweet.

First you have to create an app with twitter just follow the [link](http://www.walkswithme.net/post-to-twitter-using-php-oauth-api). 
Then Create a [Joomla content plugin](http://www.walkswithme.net/joomla-plugin-development-tutorial) with [onContentAfterSave](http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/Content#onContentAfterSave) event.

Then Once you create an article it will automatically tweets.

Hope its helps..